# Don't automatically convert hex to decimal in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed this difference for the first time.

**Python3:**

```py
>>> a = b'\x80\xad\x16\xc4\xb7\x9a'
>>> a
b'\x80\xad\x16\xc4\xb7\x9a'
>>> a[0]
128
```

**Python2:**

```py
>>> a = b'\x80\xad\x16\xc4\xb7\x9a'
>>> a
b'\x80\xad\x16\xc4\xb7\x9a'
>>> a[0]
'\x80'
```

Why is this happening first of all? And the second thing is that, I don't want python3 to convert it into decimal and want the output to be the same as that of python2, how to do that?

**EDIT:**

What I'm trying to do is pass Ethernet address as a bytearray and display it in proper notation

Code in python2:

```py
def eth_addr(a):   # a = b'\x80\xad\x16\xc4\xb7\x9a'                                                                                                                                                   
  b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]) , ord(a[1]) , ord(a[2]), ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]) , ord(a[5]))
  return b
```

When I run it in python3, it (obviously) gives me the following error:

```py
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals

Comment: @Alanhaha In that answer, in python3 `type(a[0:1])` gives `bytes` as answer whereas in python2 'type(a[0]) gives `str` as answer.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with decimal vs hex but with single bytes being represented as integers on Python 3 and the representation of non-ascii bytes in Python 2 being the hex value of the same number.

You can convert decimals to hexstrings using hex:

```
>>> a = b'\x80\xad\x16\xc4\xb7\x9a'
>>> a
b'\x80\xad\x16\xc4\xb7\x9a'
>>> hex(a[0])
'0x80'
```

Or using the `x` formatter:

```
>>> f"{a[0]:#x}"
'0x80'
>>> "%#x" % (a[0],)
'0x80'
>>> "{:#x}".format(a[0])
'0x80'
```

(drop the `#` to avoid the `0x` prefix)

---

However you can't change the int vs byte behavior.

---

**EDIT**

Your amended example is actually easier in Python 3:

```
def eth_addr(a):
    return "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5])
```

or even:

```
def eth_addr(a):
    return ":".join("%.2x" % (d,) for d in a)
```